# An adjunction between monads on $\mathcal{C}$ and presentable categories under $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, universal-algebra

Fix a regular cardinal $\kappa$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a $\kappa$-presentable $\infty$-category (comments about the 1-categorical case are welcome as well!).

I'm looking for a reference for the following statement (which in particular I hope is true).

> ***There exists a ("canonical") adjunction of $\infty$-categories***
>
> $$ Alg_{(-)}(\mathcal{C}): Monad_{\kappa}(\mathcal{C}) \rightleftharpoons  Pr^{L,\kappa}_{\mathcal{C} /}:T_{(-)} $$

Where on the left we have $\kappa$-accessible monads on $\mathcal{C}$ and on the right $\kappa$-presentable categories equipped with a left adjoint (whose right adjoint is $\kappa$-accessible of course) from $\mathcal{C}$.

The right adjoint of the adjunction should send a left adjoint functor to it's corresponding monad on $\mathcal{C}$ and the left adjoint of the adjunction should send a monad to it's category of algebras equipped with the free algebra functor from $\mathcal{C}$.

Similarly (in fact more pressingly) I would like to know if there's also a dual statement for an adjunction of the form:

> $$S_{(-)} : Pr^{L, \kappa}_{/ \mathcal{C}} \rightleftharpoons CoMonad_{\kappa}(\mathcal{C}) :CoAlg_{(-)}(\mathcal{C})$$

**Aside:** The reason I phrased the second adjunction in a more suspicious tone is I do not even know a reference for the statement that the category of coalgebras over a $\kappa$-accesible comonad on a $\kappa$-presentable category is $\kappa$-presentable (I am not even sure whether or not this should be true).

**EDIT:** I just realized that the statement for coalgebras with $\kappa = \omega$ can't be true. Indeed there are many counterexamples in categories of comodules. In light of that I could change the question to be about $\kappa > \omega$ or just remove the cardinal restriction all together. Since no answers were given yet I think it's better to just leave the question as is.

Comment: I recently worked on the exact same question and I couldn't find a reference. For the first question I needed it in a paper, and it does not seem to be treated anywhere, so I'm currently writting a proof. The second question I recently asked a reference request for the 1-categorical case of your aside on MO as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350351/presentability-rank-of-categories-of-coalgebras and it didn't get an answer. I have written a proof myself that the category of co-algebra is $\kappa$-presentable when $\kappa$ is uncountable (I don't think it is true for $\kappa=\omega$), but...

Comment: It will be difficult to upgrade this proof to the $\infty$-categorical case (it is fairly technical...)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but do you really mean "under C" rather than "over C"?  As I understand it, one of the functors in your first adjunction takes a monad T on C and outputs its category of algebras C^T together with the forgetful functor C^T --> C (which of course has a left adjoint).  That's a category *over*, not under, C.

Comment: Basically you are asking for a universal property of the presentable category of T-algebras, right? For the 1-categorical setting and $\kappa=\aleph_0$ it should follow from Prop. 6.2.15 in my thesis, right? (For which I also couldn't find a reference either.) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1716.pdf

Comment: In the 1-categorical case, a result close to what you want is Theorem 6.5 of http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/28/13/28-13abs.html, which is due to Dubuc (see Proposition 6.2 there).

Comment: @TomLeinster I think what I wrote is ok. The functor sends a monad to the corresponding free functor into the category of algebras which is a left adjoint under $\mathcal{C}$. Perhaps the confusion stems from the fact that my adjunction is covariant whereas in the result you cite it is contravariant.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, maybe my reference to Dubuc's theorem is less relevant. Not sure. What confused me was the part of your question where you wrote "categories with left adjoints".  Since a category can't have a left adjoint (!), I assumed that was an error, and that you'd meant to say that the functor from your category to C had a left adjoint. But now I guess what you meant is that the objects of your right-hand category are categories, and the maps in it are the functors that are left adjoints (i.e. have right adjoints).

Comment: Like Tom, I’d find it somehow more natural to take the maps of presentable clothes categories as following the direction of their right adjoints (not left), and so would see the RHS of your adjunction as categories *over* C, not under. This direction is more standard in the 1-categorical case, at least, and fits with conventions like the direction of geometric morphisms of (infinity-)toposes, and so on. But of course, this is just a cosmetic issue.

Comment: @TomLeinster Thanks, I tried to fix the phrasing a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: A keyword to look for that describes this situation is "semantics-structure adjunction", e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+adjunction#semanticsstructure_adjunction.  However, I think the most subtle part of the question is the preservation of the cardinal of accessibility, which (perhaps surprisingly) frequently turns out _not_ to be the case in locally-presentable-category theory.

Comment: @MikeShulman "... frequently turns out not to be the case in locally-presentable-category theory." What are some good examples demonstrating this?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/353475/22131 for references to the fact that categories of coalgebras for a $\kappa$-accessible comonad on a $\kappa$-presentable category (with $\kappa$-uncountable) is $\kappa$-presentable. The key reference is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397503003785 but some details need to be added.
To get an $\infty$-categorical version, the hard point is to generalize theorem 4.2 of the second link, whose proof is an explicit construction and is a bit technical, the rest should follows from the work of Lurie.